# how to disable back-button on rewarded video show/playing?

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

During the Rewarded video play i want to disable the back button and set a minimum waiting time . is it possible to do?On which function should i change to complete my desired functionality?
here is my code

```
 if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
     mAd.show();

 } else {
      startActivity(new Intent(EssayActivityQstnShow2.this, Essay_Answer_Show.class));
 }
```

and here is Rewarded video ads handling methods

```
    private void loadRewardedVideoAds() {
    if (!mAd.isLoaded()) {
        mAd.loadAd(getResources().getString(R.string.rewardedvideoid), new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
  //  onBackPressed();


}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {


 //   onBackPressed();

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {


    startActivity(new Intent(EssayActivityQstnShow2.this, Essay_Answer_Show.class));
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
    loadRewardedVideoAds();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    startActivity(new Intent(EssayActivityQstnShow2.this, Essay_Answer_Show.class));
}
```

Comment: Put aside on how to do it, i don't think it's a good practice to disable back button and force user to watch ads.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
private boolean isVideoPlaying;

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    isVideoPlaying = true;
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    isVideoPlaying = false;
}
```

and than `onBackPress()` check, if the video is playing or not

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!isVideoPlaying)
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Before implementing this, please read the [policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128543?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) carefully.

Comment: thanks for your replay . but its not working for me

Comment: @Mustakkhadem This is due to new activity is open and you don't have access to that activity

Answer (score 0):

You must override the `onBackPressed` callback in activity and remove line `super.onBackPressed()`. then if the user taps the back button the activity will not close.

If you have no access to the `Essay_Answer_Show` activity check can you create another activity which extends that or clone library and tries to modify activity?

Comment: thanks for your quick response . i have tried with a boolean variable to disable the onBackPressed method whenever the Rewarded video ads is playing !